# NDVI value range- Does NDVI always lie between -1 to 1?

Tags: image-processing, geotiff

I am working with Landsat 8 images. I need to calculate NDVI and display it. For display purpose, I need to scale the NDVI values to 0 to 255 range. 
NDVI is basically (p(4)-p(3))/(p(4)+p(3))..where p(4) and p(3) are reflectance corresponding to band 4 and band 3 respectively. These reflectance values can be calculated from metadata available while downloading Landsat imagery.
Now, the metadata file also mentions the maximum and minimum possible reflectance value for the given scene.(* I have attached a picture below). 
Now considering a case of p(4) as max value 1.2107 and p(3) as min value -0.09998. The NDVI comes out to be (1.2107-(-0.09998))/(1.2107+(-0.09998)) = 1.18.
The literature I've read about NDVI says NDVI always falls between -1 to 1. But this clearly doesn't follow for the above mentioned case. So I am confused as to what range of NDVI values should I scale to 0 to 255 for display purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

The input values are expected to fall in the range `0` to `1`, as they are the ratio of the reflected radiation to the incoming radiation - where `1` represents perfect reflection and 0 represents total absorption of radiation. So, if a plant reflects 20% in band 3 and 80% band 4, your values should be p3=0.2 and p4=0.8.

On a purely intuitive level, we could look at b3 and b4 varyoing between 0 and 1. If both b3 and b4 are either zero or one, the NDVI numerator becomes zero and with it the NDVI ratio. So, we are left with the case where b3=1 and b4=0, which is the opposite of what vegetation does (real vegetation reflects more in b4 than b3), and that would lead to an NDVI=-1. And, finally, the case we are expecting where something reflects nothing in b3 (i.e. b3=0) and reflects perfectly in b4 (i.e. b4=1), this leads to the classic *signature* of vegetation with an NDVI=1, or at least a relatively high ratio.

Your values are clearly in a different range, so you would need to investigate their units - they should not have any units as they are themselves pure ratios of reflected to incoming radiation.